# DevExpress GridView.SaveLayoutToStream not saving FindFilterText

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a Winforms app that has a DevExpress GridView. I would like to save the layout using SaveLayoutToStream, but when I do so, it does not retain the value of the GridView's FindFilterText. Is there any way to make it do this?

ETA:
DevExpress version 11.1
.NET framework version 4.0

Comment: What version of DevExpress are you using?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation...

Specific options which are disabled in the options parameter are not stored. 
To save all the options pass null or a static DevExpress.Utils.OptionsLayoutBase.FullLayout property as the options parameter.

The SaveLayoutToStream method overload without the options parameter saves only the options which are defined by the ColumnView.OptionsLayout property.

Not sure which method overload you are using.  They don't mention which specific options are not stored.

I would trying the save all by passing in the FullLayout value to the parameter if you are not using that.

Comment: Its probably also a property of the GridView itself.